# I want my service to terminate itself from within a thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a service that spins up a server which handles calls. The server can only start under certain conditions, and the service should try to start the server for a couple of minutes before giving up. Therefor, I use the service interface methods only to spin up a thread that handles the "try starting server and retry if it failed"-logic. But now I need to add termination of the service, if the server was not successfully started after, say, 5 minutes. The problem is, that I do not know how to marshal a call back to the service's "main" thread, since, as far as I understand, it is not an STA thread where I can just use a dispatcher. It is my understanding that I would have to do that in order to be able to `System.Exit(1)` my service. Any advice?

Points of clarification:

- I do spin up a thread that is basically the service's main thread. Terminating that thread, however, does not couse the service to appear as stopped.

Comment: Assuming your service's main thread is in some kind of loop, just set a flag somewhere that you check within that loop (making sure you lock on something when getting and setting the flag) and exit if the flag is true.

Comment: you can also throw a fatal exception and have it handled in the main thread

Comment: That's the whole point - when Windows starts up my service, there's an onStart() Method where I bring up my service thread. But if I just terminate that thread, it doesn't make the service appear as stopped in the service control panel.

Comment: Throwing an exception in `OnStart()` will cause the service to register as having failed its startup. There's no kind of marshaling, you have to take care of waiting on your code (`Thread.Join`) and evaluating the results yourself. If you can, use a task rather than a thread, since those can actually return values and don't require you to write your own synchronization.

Comment: I need more time than `OnStart()` allows for (30 seconds), so I can't throw from within `OnStart()`.

Comment: Then don't. Throwing an exception on any independent thread will also terminate your service, and it will register as having terminated unexpectedly (and restarted if it's configured to do so). If your service isn't terminating, then somewhere the exception is being handled. Notably, `Systems.Timers.Timer` is notorious for swallowing exceptions in its `Elapsed` handler, so make sure you're not using that.

Comment: You have control of your thread pool. Do your job  threads have status flags or other indicators of success or failures, can they abort and report? Just monitor their outcomes in the threadpool controller and exit gracefully from the scope of the service.

Comment: [`Environment.Exit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) has no limitations on where it's called from. That being said, if your "startup" thread exiting isn't causing the process to shut down, I'd spend a bit more time working out what else is keeping the process alive before resorting to this particular sledgehammer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you a tip and if you don't manage to implement it I will edit it later with more details. When you want to stop the service you should call the `ServiceBase.Stop` method.

Spin up a task to do the "try starting server and retry if it failed" and add a continuation (or pass `Stop` as `Action` argument) that will be executed when the task completes based on the result (or alternatively if you throw exception on failed to start, then verify `Task.IsFaulted` and call `Stop()` if true).